# Atualizar app.config ou web.config via código

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um robo que lê todas as linhas de vários arquivos contidos numa pasta. Porém preciso saber qual foi o ultimo arquivo e linha lidos para que eu possa retomar quando preciso for.

Pensei em colocar no banco de dados, mas imaginando que terei +10 milhões de linhas, não seria legal ficar atualizando toda hora. Então tive a ideia de inseri-lo no meu arquivo de configuração.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LastFileReaded" value="xpto1.sql"/>
    <add key="LastLineIndex" value="29990"/>
</appSettings>
```

Porém levando em conta essa abordagem precisaria atualizar esse valores, a pergunta é:

Olhando de forma semântica, é incorreto utilizar essa abordagem? E como eu faria para atualizar o valor dessa chave diretamente no web.config ou app.config?

Comment: Perguntada 50seg atrás, a pessoa nem lê ou critica e já negativa rsrs

Comment: Não entendi bem, vais ter *"+10 milhões de linhas"* e preferes salvar num arquivo de configuração que num banco de dados, que já tem estrutura própria para gerenciar milhões de leituras/escritas?

Comment: Ricardo eu tenho vários arquivos SQL e eu vou receber todas as linhas(INSERT) a ideia seria percorrer e ir executando até o fim por isso preciso armazenar... Você me recomenda gerenciar via banco de dados?

Comment: humm entendi... nos seus arquivos SQL já vem o comando pronto (`insert...`) ou vem os dados e tens que montar os comandos pra executar?

Comment: Faz mais sentido você persistir essa informação no banco de dados... Crie uma tabela com essa informação e vá atualizando conforme a execução. Depois consulte ela quando for executar uma nova rotina

Comment: @RicardoPontual já vem os comandos prontos,mas não consigo executar o SQL direto pois são arquivos GIGANTES

Comment: entendi, só mais uma dúvida: qual banco de dados está usando? talvez um *bulk insert* funcione melhor, mais rápido e performático

Comment: Mysql, só preciso armazenar um índice e um nome de arquivo...

Comment: publiquei uma resposta com uma sugestão, usar o arquivo de configuração, mas um arquivo alterantivo

Answer (score 0):

Pode sempre criar um ficheiro de `Settings`, onde depois pode atualizar os valores de forma simples:

```
using MyApp.Properties;

// por propriedade
Settings.Default.var1 = "teste";
Settings.Default.var2 = 10;
Settings.Default.var3 = true;
Settings.Default.Save();

// por chave
Settings.Default["var1"] = "teste";
Settings.Default["var2"] = 10;
Settings.Default["var3"] = true;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Se for para coisas simples, basicamente armazenar informação em tipos "primitivos" (`string`, `int`, `bool`, etc), pode utilizar à vontade, mas se for algo mais complexo, um objeto de tipo não-primitivo, recomenda-se algo mais.

Comment: É bem primitivo sim, é um robo que eu vou utilizar uma vez na vida... caso eu feche o software, reinicie o PC o `Settings` continua armazenado?

Comment: Sim, continua, penso que fica em `%userprofile%\appdata\local` com o nome do software ou empresa.

Comment: Boa vou testar...

Answer (score 0):

> Olhando de forma semântica, é incorreto utilizar essa abordagem?

Sim e muito errado, principalmente a quantidade que voce quer armazenar o arquivo so suporta ate 250kb(`KLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB`)
 e tem uma limitacao de caracteres (nao me recordo ao certo mas algo por volta de 30.000).

como @Ricardo Pontual sugeriu a melhor solucao 'e usar banco de dados.

fora que toda vez que vc escreve no web.config vc reseta a aplicacao com a nova configuracao.

Comment: Hudson a ideia não é guardar todos os arquivos e linhas a ideia é guardar somente o número da ultima linha inserida e ultimo arquivo na qual esta linha estava

Comment: se vc vai ter  "terei +10 milhões de linhas," no db vc vai ter no config tambem nao? pq se o config faz com 2 linhas o db tambem faz.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti acabei de colocar um outro bom motivo de nao usar o web.config para isso, pq vc vai resetar a aplicacao e cada edicao feita.

Comment: Perfeito Hudson, obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um arquivo de configuração específico para esse fim, sem precisar escrever no **Web.config** ou **App.config**.

Suponha que você crie o arquivo "importacao.config" com essa estrutura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<configuration>  
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="LastFileReaded" value="xpto1.sql"/>
    <add key="LastLineIndex" value="29990"/>
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

Para ler este arquivo, use a classe `ExeConfigurationFileMap` do namespace `System.Configuration`:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "importacao.config";


Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var lastFileReaded = config.AppSettings.Settings["LastFileReaded"].Value;
```

Para alterar, basta setar um valor na chave e salvar usando o método `Save`:

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```